# .js, css or html - how change object to two different colors?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, colors

I ask participants yes/no questions in an experiment and they answer by keypress (Y/N). Now, I want to display YES green and NO red.

I'm doing this with Ibex farms where you have an experiment file in .js format. In this file, one defines the "Question controller" as follows:

```
"Question", {
    as: [["Y","Yes"],["N","No"]],   //defines keys+answer displays
 }
```

Adding html tags `<font-size>, <div style>` in this line did not work.
Besides that, there is a .css file in which I can change the color for both answers, but give the same color to both:

```
span.Question-fake-link {
color: #ff6600;   //changing this to red; both Yes and No are red now 
cursor: pointer;
}
```

The third file is a Question.js file which defines behavior and properties of the question controller beyond its appearance. It is too long to post here, I think, and I don't have authorship. But in there, the answers are defined as "left Comment" and "right Comment". So I attempted to add the 4th line at the (I hope) relevant place:

```
var lcd = $(document.createElement("li"))
                  .addClass(this.cssPrefix + "scale-comment-box")
                  .append(this.leftComment);                             
                  .document.getElementById("leftComment").style.color =   "red";    //added this, made experiment dysfunctional                    
this.xl.append(lcd);
```

Does anyone know how to change the colours individually?

I'm sorry, I know this must look complicated, but maybe someone can give me a pointer on what to do...If you need more of the scripts, please let me know.

Many thanks.

**EDIT**: After trying out some of the suggestions here, I see the answers are somehow as "span.fake-link". Maybe this code snippet can help (line 1/2):

```
var a = $(document.createElement("span")).addClass(this.cssPrefix + "fake-link");
        __Question_answers__[i] = ans;
        __Question_callback__ = function (i) {
            var answerTime = new Date().getTime();
            var ans = __Question_answers__[i];
            var correct = "NULL";
            if (! (t.hasCorrect === false)) {...}
             }
```

But how can I replace "span" or "fake-link"? I guess I have to replace both. Removing the span.fake-link properties in css-files doesn't seem to help.

**EDIT**: Or could this be the problem?

```
 if ((this.presentAsScale || this.presentHorizontally) && this.leftComment) {
        var lcd = $(document.createElement("li"))
            .addClass(this.cssPrefix + "scale-comment-box")
            .append(this.leftComment)                        
            .appendTo(this.xl)
       this.xl.append(lcd);
         }
```

I attempted to replace "scale-comment-box" by "red" (defined as a class in css before), but that also doesn't help.

Comment: it is dysfunctional because you have a semi-colon at the end of append(this.leftComment);

Comment: Why do you use jquery and mixin js ?? And your overall structure is unclear to me.

Comment: @Nawed Khan: Alright, now the experiment works, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Jonas w: I didn't make the files, I just modify them and write my final experiment file. They're available like that if you want to design an online reading experiment, for example. It took me a little while to figure out the structure myself.

Comment: @jira this code isnt really well written ( or at least the snippets ypuve providef arent) , are you shure you want to mess around with this?

Comment: @Jonas w: The author himself even says in the script that it's messy code. I don't really want to mess with it, no...but I guess I need to try as I'm not happy with how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use jquerys css function:

```
$("<li>")
.addClass(this.cssPrefix + "scale-comment-box")
.css({color:"red"})
.append(this.leftComment)                        
.appendTo(this.xl);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to Javascript, so I'm not sure I got you right. I attempted to add your code into the .js script, so:
`var lcd = $(document.createElement("li")), 

..., .append(this.leftComment); 
[YOUR CODE]; 
this.xl.append(lcd);`
This did not change any colour, but moved NO into the next line.
Putting your code **below** `this.xl.append(lcd);` changed nothing. I guess I'm going wrong somewhere.

Comment: @jira If the variable lcd is really needed ( somewhere else ), you can add var lcd = before the first line of the upper code

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it still doesn't change anything.

Comment: I edited my original post, added some info at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Javascript, is it feasible for you to add two extra css classes?
One could be .red and the other, .green and then append those classes to the element accordingly at creation:

```
//CSS
.red{
   color:#F00;
}
.green{
   color:#0F0;
}
//javascript
//Your javascript seems to be a mix of jQuery and JS so I assume jQuery is imported.  If this is incorrect, you would need to use a raw javascript solution 
//Hint:  Look at document.getElementsByClassName and .classname += "red"
//jQuery version:
$("li").addClass("red") //for any items that need to be red.  replace red with green for the green items
```

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added the newly defined classes in the .css file and the `$("li)...` into the Question.js file to where `leftComment, rightComment` are defined. It changed nothing:

`if ((this.presentAsScale || this.presentHorizontally) && this.leftComment) {            var lcd = $(document.createElement("li"))
                      .addClass(this.cssPrefix + "scale-comment-box")
                      .addClass("red")               //your suggestion
                      .append(this.leftComment)
               this.xl.append(lcd);  
        }`
Probably my mistake...

Comment: since you've already got an addClass function in there, change it to .addClass(this.cssPrefix+"scale-comment-box red") and take out the .addClass("red") line.

Comment: Hm. I must still be missing something. Now that I've also taken out my initial change of the `span.fake-link` to green and added the new changes, everything is back to blue. I can't see where that's defined. I suspect the changes you're suggesting are overridden somewhere, but I can't figure out where, it's been hours. Or could it be that changing them is impossible b/c they're defined as the ominous "fake link"?

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser and inspect the specific element you're trying to color to figure out what classes are applied to it.  You can also make some test changes to the CSS in those tools to see what finally makes it work.  At that point, it would be easier to pin point where the code needs to be changed in your project.  You should also try Jonas w's solution and see if that gives you the desired effect

Comment: I tried Jonas w's solution and commented it, it didn't help, unfortunately. F12 doesn't do anything, CTRL+Shift+K opens the Console in Firefox, it that it? It opens a bunch of windows, but only few actually give info. I should open it to the experiment itself, right? Not the Question.js that defines the question. I also added a bit of info to my original post.